# Laravel composite key 2 table?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

How do we Join and insert and query the data for 2 tables with the same key?

Table 1

- SID pk
- fname
- lname
- dop
- gender

Table 2

- SID fk
- zipcode pk
- city
- state
- county

Insert function code

```
    $SID = $request->get('SID');
    $fname = $request->get('fname');$lname = $request->get('lname');$dob = $request->get('dob');$gender = $request->get('gender');

    if(is_numeric($SID) && !empty($fname) && !empty($lname) && !empty($dob) && !empty($gender)){
            DB::table('student')->insert([
                'SID' =>$SID,
                'fname' =>$starttime,
                'lname' =>$lname,
                'dob' =>$dob,
                'gender' =>$gender,
                'created_at' =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),]);
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins

Comment: Please don't use an image for code, put it directly in the question as formatted text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume your request has the rest of the columns for table 2:

```
DB::table('student')->insert([
            'SID' =>$SID,
            'fname' =>$starttime,
            'lname' =>$lname,
            'dob' =>$dob,
            'gender' =>$gender,
            'created_at' =>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),]);

$id = DB::table('student')->select('SID')->where('SID',$SID);

DB::table('table2')->insert([
            'SID' =>$id,
            'zipcode' =>$request->input('zipcode'),
            'city' =>$request->input('city'),
            'state' =>$request->input('state'),
            'country' =>$request->input('country')
            ]);
```

Comment: Would like to ask more knowledge. If you add table 3 table 4 again, are you doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but why do you need to insert into 4 tables at the same time, but if you had to use [transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#database-transactions) that Laravel proviedes.